# Structured Logs in Google Cloud Run not being parsed (using Winston for logging)

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, winston, google-cloud-run

I'm attempting to format my logs in such a way that Google Cloud will correctly extract the log level. This is running on Cloud Run, with typescript. Cloud Run is grabbing the logs from the container output.

If I do the following, google correctly parses the log line:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({
   severity: 'ERROR',
   message: 'This is testing a structured log error for GCP'
}));
```

And the log output looks like this:
[image: log level error]

I've tried a number of different ways to format with winston, ended up with the following:

```
useFormat = format.combine(
      format((info, opts) => {
        info['severity'] = info.level;
        delete info.level;
        return info;
      })(),
      format.json());


    this.winston = winston.createLogger({
      level: logLevel,
      format: useFormat,
      transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
    });
```

Which looks like it will work (it correctly outputs the json line), I get this in the GCP logs:
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out I was close, just needed to .upperCase() the log level (and I'm mapping Verbose -> Debug, I don't really understand why GCP decided to do a totally different log leveling system than everyone else). New code:

```
useFormat = 
    format.combine(
      format((info, opts) => {
        let level = info.level.toUpperCase();
          if(level === 'VERBOSE') {
            level = 'DEBUG';
          }

          info['severity'] = level;
          delete info.level;
          return info;
      })(),
      format.json());
```

Comment: Hi @patrickWhite good job finding the answer for your question. Please accept it for better visibility for another SO users.

Comment: Stackdriver log-levels are documented in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity, and are based on https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#section-6.2.1, "verbose" has always struck me not as a level but as a request for more output... such as showing those debug logs.

Comment: I wish as a community we had just used 1 to N for log levels so people could use it as they see fit, but most libraries have settled with a debug and a verbose, and NOT having a critical, so stack driver is just a bit of an impedance mismatch.  But, appears to be working, now to figure out some of the nice bells and whistles around tracing, etc.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that Google offers a winston transport for Cloud Logging.
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/logging-winston/latest

Answer (score 0):

The last bit of the question is confusing. The problem OP is pointing to is that the json is printed out and the severity is default. The json should not be printed out, only the message, and the severity should be debug.  The answer that OP provides does what is wanted.

For others that may be confused in the same way I was.

Comment: More of a comment rather then an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31565765)